# Craft Neo – childs Output

Tags: layout, plugin-neo

I have a question. How can I output the Childs from a Neo (Neo Plugin) Block?

With this code, i get the output for all level 1 blocks but i don't get a output for the deeper levels.

And how can I handle different child templates for the Output?

My idea is to have a switch with different case for the level 2 output. Because i've different child block options.

```
{% for block in entry.MatrixNeo.level(1) %}
    {% switch block.type.handle %}

        {% case 'title' %}
            <h2>{{ block.mainTitle }}</h2>


        {% case 'boxes' %}
             <h2>{{ block.mainTitle }}</h2>   

            {% for item in block.children %}
                {% switch block.type.handle %}

                    {% case 'box' %}
                        <h2>{{ block.mainTitle }}</h2>

                        {% case 'image' %}
                        <h2>{{ block.mainTitle }}</h2>

                {% endswitch %}
            {% endfor %}

    {% endswitch %}
{% endfor %}
```

Can somebody help me out, please?

=====================

UPDATE

Now my code works fine but i've a new questione:

How can i output a real Matix-Field in a child element (level 2 in Neo).

My Code:

```
{% nav block in entry.myField.level(1) %}
    {% switch block.type.handle %}
        {% case 'title' %}
            <hgroup>
                <h2>{{ block.mainTitle }}</h2>
                <h4>{{ block.subTitle }}</h4>
            </hgroup>

        {% case 'intro' %}
            <section class="block">
                {% for item in block.children %}
                    {% include "_includes/elements/" ~ item.type %}
                {% endfor %}
            </section>

    {% endswitch %}
{% endnav %}
```

The child Code:

```
<div class="box">
    <h2>{{ item.mainTitle }}</h2>

    {% for button in block.myButton %}
        {% switch button.type %}
            {% case 'buttonIntern' %}
                <a class="button" href="{{ button.linkIntern }}">{{ button.linkText }}</a>

            {% case 'buttonExtern' %}
                <a class="button" target="_blank" href="{{ button.linkIntern }}">{{ button.linkExtern }}</a>

        {% endswitch %}
    {% endfor %}

</div>
```

Comment: Is `MatrixNeo` a native [Matrix](https://craftcms.com/docs/matrix-fields) field or a [Neo](https://github.com/benjamminf/craft-neo) field from the Neo plugin? And what type of field is `children` in `block.children`?

Comment: Yes, the Neo-Plugin. My idea is to have a `switch` with different `case` in the level 2 output. Because i've different child block options.

Comment: Per your updated question. When I see people putting a Matrix within a Neo my first question is why? I can't think of any reason(there might be some) that if you've committed to using NEO, you'd need a Matrix field. You could create a "button" block type in NEO which has two children; one External Link and one Internal Link and use the same code approach as the original answer.

Comment: Per your updated code, maybe the issue is you have button.linkIntern as the link in your buttonExtern call.

Comment: You are right, it make no sense at all. Now I build it as a Neo block, but I can't output the button in the 3th level with the some technic as the level 2 blocks. Can you tell me how to output the 3th level blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your above code is not working because you are using "block" instead of "item" in your children. So...

```
{% for item in block.children %}
    {% switch item.type.handle %}
```

You don't necessarily need to do a switch here, you could do a series of includes and make their file names match your block type... so "_includes/neo/box.twig" and "_includes/neo/image.twig"

In the example below I am replacing "item" with "child" to explain it better.

```
{% for block in entry.MatrixNeo.level(1) %}
      <h2>{{ block.mainTitle }}</h2>
      {% for child in block.children %}
           {% include "_includes/neo/" ~ child.type %}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must call the inner blocks (level2, level3 and so on) like the first level

```
{% if entry.bodyMain is defined and entry.bodyMain | length %}
    {% nav block in entry.bodyMain.level(1) %}
        {% switch block.type.handle %}

            {% case 'accordion' %}
                <ul class="accordion accordion-2">

                    {% nav block in block.children %}
                        {% switch block.type.handle %}

                            {% case 'timeBlock' %}
                                <li>
                                    <a class="opener" href="#">{{ block.heading }}</a>
                                    <div class="slide">
                                        {{ block.body }}
                                    </div>
                                </li>

                        {% endswitch %}
                    {% endnav %}

                </ul>

        {% endswitch %}
    {% endnav %}
{% endif %}
```

Or you can do it like this:

```
{% if entry.bodyMain is defined and entry.bodyMain | length %}
    {% nav block in entry.bodyMain.level(1) %}
        {% switch block.type.handle %}

            {% case 'accordion' %}
                <ul class="accordion accordion-2">
                    {% for block in block.children %}
                        {% include "_includes/_blocks/" ~ block.type %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>

        {% endswitch %}
    {% endnav %}
{% endif %}
```

For that you must build a file with this content:

```
<li>
    <a class="opener" href="#">{{ block.heading }}</a>
    <div class="slide">
        {{ block.body }}
    </div>
</li>
```